# MATLAB GUIDE handles variable only updates after 2 callbacks

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am having an issue with a handles variable `handles.scanOne`.
I initialize it `handles.scanOne = struct([]);`. The relevant callback is

```
function getButton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
loadText(handles, hObject, 1, 'Select the original scans')
loadAxes(handles, 1)
```

and loadText updates the handles variable while loadAxes uses the updated variable.

```
function loadText(handles, hObject, region, displayMessage)
...
...
handles.scanOne = struct('imageArray', imageArray, 'patientNumber', patientNumber, ...
        'scanNumber', scanNumber, 'pathName', pathname, 'maxPixel', maxPixel);
guidata(hObject,handles)
```

However, when I test my GUI the first time the button callback, handles.scanOne is updated within `loadText`, but is not updated for the entire structure. When I press the button again, `handles.scanOne` is updated for the entire structure.

Edit: I think I might know the problem. The `handles` structure passed into the button callback is still the original one. The `handles` structure has been updated by loadText, but that new structure is not passed into anything in the button callback. The following link has a solution to my problem: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/122423-gui-how-to-update-the-handles-when-calling-a-function-callback-inside-another-callback

Comment: do you have this command at the end of the `getButton1_Callback`? : `guidata(hObject,handles)`

Comment: I do not have it at the end of the `getButton1_Callback`, but do for the `loadText `, which it calls.

Comment: while using GUIDE you must have `guidata(hObject, handles)` at the end of all sub functions

Answer (score 0):

I ended up not storing everything in the handles structures and instead used 
`setappdata(objectHandle, 'var', var)` and `getappdata(objectHandle, 'var')`. I no longer had to use `guidata(hObject, handles)` as a result and it made thinking about the handles structure much easier.